# Which are Linear homogeneous recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine which of the following are linear homogeneous recurrence relations with constant coefficients and state the degree/order of those that are. If they are not, say which property of the definition they lack.
$$a_n=3a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} + 5a_{n-4}$$
$$a_n=2na_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$
$$a_n=a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n-2}$$

I assumed that the difference between the non-linear and linear was that non-linear approached $0$, and the linear approached a function.

So my answer was :
linear
1.)$$a_n=3a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} + 5a_{n-4}$$
2.)$$a_n=a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n-2}$$

Non-Linear: $$a_n=2na_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$$
Because the leading $2n$ is not the proper format.

Why am I wrong? What would it be, and why?

Comment: Your answer is correct except that for the third relation where the reasoning should be : the coefficient is $2n$ which is a variable (depends on $n$) hence it is not CONSTANT coefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand the definitions.

"Linear" means that the
$a_m$
occur to the first power
and are multiplied
only be constants.

For example,
$3a_n$ and $-32767a_{k+1}$
are linear terms.
$3na_{n-4}$ is *not* linear
because $3n$ is not a constant.

"Homogeneous" means that
only terms of the form
of an expression not involving
the $a_m$
multiplied by a number of the $a_m$
that is the same for 
all terms.
The number of these
$a_m$ is called the
"degree" of the term.

For example,
$3a_j a_k$ 
is of degree two,
and
$-12a_m$ is of degree one.
$3a_j a_k-17a_m^2$ 
is homogeneous of degree two.
$3a_j a_k-17a_m$
is not homogeneous
because it has one term of degree two
and one term of degree one.

If you understand these,
you should be able to answer the questions.